# for loop getting ignored in function but works perfectly fine in console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, video, javascript-objects

so i have this code

```js
  var moviepop = await getMovies();
  for (let i = 0; i < moviepop.length; i++) {
      var html = `
        <button class="cell-more-button">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-vertical"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"/><circle cx="12" cy="5" r="1"/><circle cx="12" cy="19" r="1"/></svg>
        </button>
          <div class="product-cell image">
            <img onclick="fullsize(this)" src="${
              "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300" + moviepop[i].backdrop_path
            }" alt="product">
            <span>${moviepop[i].title}</span>
          </div>
        <div class="product-cell category"><span class="cell-label">Category:</span>Movies</div>
        <div class="product-cell status-cell">
          <span class="cell-label">Status:</span>
          <span class="status active">Available</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell sales"><span class="cell-label">Downloads:</span>${downloads(
          moviepop[i].id
        )}</div>
        <div class="product-cell stock"><span class="cell-label">Release year:</span>${moviepop[
          i
        ].release_date.replaceAll("-", "/")}</div>
        <div class="product-cell price"><span class="cell-label">Rating:</span>${
          moviepop[i].vote_average
        }</div>
        `;
      console.log(html);
      var movie = document.createElement("div");
      movie.className = "products-row";
      movie.innerHTML = html;
      document.getElementById("baba").appendChild(movie);
  }
```

some more code

```js
async function loadData() {
  var moviepop = await getMovies();
  for (let i = 0; i < moviepop.length; i++) {
      var html = `
        <button class="cell-more-button">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-vertical"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"/><circle cx="12" cy="5" r="1"/><circle cx="12" cy="19" r="1"/></svg>
        </button>
          <div class="product-cell image">
            <img onclick="fullsize(this)" src="${
              "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300" + moviepop[i].backdrop_path
            }" alt="product">
            <span>${moviepop[i].title}</span>
          </div>
        <div class="product-cell category"><span class="cell-label">Category:</span>Movies</div>
        <div class="product-cell status-cell">
          <span class="cell-label">Status:</span>
          <span class="status active">Available</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell sales"><span class="cell-label">Downloads:</span>${downloads(
          moviepop[i].id
        )}</div>
        <div class="product-cell stock"><span class="cell-label">Release year:</span>${moviepop[
          i
        ].release_date.replaceAll("-", "/")}</div>
        <div class="product-cell price"><span class="cell-label">Rating:</span>${
          moviepop[i].vote_average
        }</div>
        `;
      console.log(html);
      var movie = document.createElement("div");
      movie.className = "products-row";
      movie.innerHTML = html;
      document.getElementById("baba").appendChild(movie);
  }
}
```

I'm getting some movie information from an array and trying to create some HTML divs with that information but it's not doing anything I think it's getting ignored but when I run the same code outside the function in the console it works perfectly fine?

Comment: what do you mean by outside the function ? You for loop is not in a function on your code.

Comment: i added some changes i might give you more context of what i mean

Comment: What do getShows and getMovies return. Any errors in your browser console

Comment: you await getShow() and getMovies(), are you sure there is no error with that ? Because await will stop the function until it is resolved

Comment: You assign showspop in the first code then try to iterate moviespop

Comment: oh wait thats my mistake copying the code and no there's no error getting the array

Comment: i fixed it sorry

Comment: Show one of those functions you await. You're probably doing it worng in them. I.e. the function you await.  What does that look like

Comment: To loop an array you can use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). `var` creates a variable in the parent scope, so `const` might be more suitable for your definitions here, unless you need that functionality of `var`.

Comment: @undefined what difference will that make.  Hint: none in this code. Also var does NOT create a variable in the parent scope at all. Where did you learn that?

Comment: @Bravo In my opinion, it's more readable. OP seems to be using an array (or another iterable of some sort) and `for..in` and `for..of` are specifically designed for this, as far as I am aware

```(() => {
 for (let i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
  var x = 0;
 }
 return x;
})()
```
variable `x` is accessible in parent scope as it is defined with `var`. function returns 0

Comment: get movies returns

Comment: ```
0: {adult: false, backdrop_path: '/wcKFYIiVDvRURrzglV9kGu7fpfY.jpg', genre_ids: Array(3), id: 453395, original_language: 'en', …}
1: {adult: false, backdrop_path: '/zGLHX92Gk96O1DJvLil7ObJTbaL.jpg', genre_ids: Array(3), id: 338953, original_language: 'en', …}
2: {adult: false, backdrop_path: '/egoyMDLqCxzjnSrWOz50uLlJWmD.jpg', genre_ids: Array(4), id: 675353, original_language: 'en', …}
3: {adult: false, backdrop_path: '/t0mwKhUDa62hdhdKSsN4xMfhY5Z.jpg', genre_ids: 
```

Comment: Dont put that in comment. It returns that? Not a promise? Why are you awaiting that if it doesn't return a promise

Comment: oh it returns a promise